# Wordpress strange text over the content of json-api plugin

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I use WordPress 4.1.1.
I tried to install the [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/json-api) plugin.

Strange letters are displayed above the JSON content. And they update after refresh of the page.

I tried to bring another letter under the code of plugin. These letters appeared under these figures, so is the problem in the WordPress system?

Please help me to understand and to remove them, because I can't parse my JSON.

[image]

On localhost it works fine with the same properties and data...

The letter are: 7b00c, 78709, 6eb3d... and they change with updates..

Comment: show your headers and code where you return your json

Comment: Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8

Comment: json-api plugin return all json. But the problem is not in plugin, because i put echo "sadasd"; under the code of plugin and all the json data appears below...but not these letters - frome above

Comment: try to clean output buffer before output json. If that helps - search for any echo or symbols output in your php files

Comment: ob_clean() dont clear this letters

Comment: We have found an extra header Transfer-Encoding:chunked. How to solve it?

Comment: Solved. We delete the row:  header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK', true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strange characters is probably a `chunk-size`.

#### Content-Length

When a server-side process sends a response through an HTTP server, the data will typically be stored in a buffer before it is transmitted to the client (browser). If the entire response fits in the buffer in a timely manner, the server will declare the size in a `Content-Length:` header, and send the response as-is to the client.

#### Chunked Transfer Coding

If the response does *not* fit in the buffer, or the server decides to vacate the buffer for other reasons before the full size is known, it will instead send the response in chunks. This is indicated by the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header. Each chunk is preceeded by its length in hexadecimal (followed by a `CRLF`-pair). The end of the response is indicated by a `0` chunk-size. The exact syntax is detailed below.

#### Solution

If you are parsing the HTTP response yourself, there are all sorts of intricacies that you need to consider. Chunked encoding is one of them. You need to check for the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header and assemble the response by parsing and stripping out the `chunk-size` parts.

It's much easier to use a library such as [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) which will handle all the details for you.

One hack to avoid chunks is to send the response using [HTTP/1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) rather than [HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230). In HTTP/1.0, the length is indicated either by the `Content-Length:` header, or by closing the connection.

#### Syntax

This is the syntax for chunked bodies specified in [**RFC 7230 - "Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing"**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) ([ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) notation):

> ```
> 4.1.  Chunked Transfer Coding
>  chunked-body   = *chunk
>                   last-chunk
>                   trailer-part
>                   CRLF
>
>  chunk          = chunk-size [ chunk-ext ] CRLF
>                   chunk-data CRLF
>  chunk-size     = 1*HEXDIG
>  last-chunk     = 1*("0") [ chunk-ext ] CRLF
>
>  chunk-data     = 1*OCTET ; a sequence of chunk-size octets
>
>  trailer-part   = *( header-field CRLF )
> ```