# Why is Wordpress showing data in json format?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to debug where is the issue. Actually my [website](http://bascalligraphers.com) is showing encrypted data without any reason. Can anyone guide me where is the issue i will appreciate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress strange text over the content of json-api plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025663/wordpress-strange-text-over-the-content-of-json-api-plugin)

Comment: @Abhijeet not duplicate at all. The website linked by the poster doesn't display any JSON. It is the victim of some malware that, for some reason (probably a configuration mismatch) displays its source code instead of executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your server or the code of your website has a security vulnerability that has been exploited. The "encrypted" text it displays is actually just encoded (encryption and encoding are different things) and it is the code of the malware that was injected into your site.

You should find and fix the vulnerability. This is a very big issue, this is not the appropriate place to discuss about it. Contact the administrator of your server.

Then you install a fresh copy of Wordpress, the theme and the plugins your site is using and keep it updated.